# Apollo recovery zone(s)

Tags: apollo-program, reentry, landing-site

For the Apollo missions that left Earth orbit, were there multiple recovery zones for each splashdown?  How big was each zone?

Comment: I don't know how big the designated recovery zones actually were, but they didn't *need* to be very big in practice: each of the lunar Apollo flights landed within 3 nautical miles of their targeted location, none of them more than 13 nautical miles from the recovery ship. https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029.pdf

Comment: @RussellBorogove that is excellent information, and source.  Thanks.

Comment: Even Apollo 13 did a very precise splashdown. "The impact point was about 1.0 n  mi from the target point and 3.5 n  mi from the recovery ship U.S.S. 
Iwo lima." To save time on return "A 263.82-second transearth injection maneuver using the LM descent propulsion system was executed at 079:27:38.95 to speed up the return to Earth by 860.5 ft/sec after the docked spacecraft had swung around the far side of the Moon" Amazing precision despite a mission abort and a modified return trajectory. Cites from Apollo by the Numbers.